# Extract the right year, month, and day MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Hi everyone I have a date data like this 23/01/22 (dd/mm/yy), I want to extract the year with EXTRACT(YEAR from date) it returns the value of 2023 instead of 2022. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Because `23/01/22` it is not stored as a date , but as a string. Always use proper date datatype

Comment: That's one of the reasons to use proper data types, instead of using strings or varchar for everything. The best solution is to modify your database to use date/datetime types

Answer (score 2):

Always use proper date datatype.

Workaround:

```
select EXTRACT(YEAR from str_to_date('23/01/22','%d/%m/%y')) ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ef455c01586b5b0cee2d13b49dc2cc56